# Toggle between \dfrac and \tfrac in integrals

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, texstudio

I would like to learn how auto-program my document to display integrals with fractions nicely.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{10}} \frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}$ \vspace{1cm} %standard display

$\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3}{2}}$ \vspace{1cm} %standard display 

\end{document}
```

What I would like to know is how do I program it so that if you have a limits with fractions use \tfrac for the limits but if you have a fraction on it own, use \dfrac.

Desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\int_{\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{10}} \dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}$ \vspace{1cm} %uses \tfrac for limits and \dfrac for fraction

$\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3}{2}}$ \vspace{1cm}  %uses \dfrac because its a fraction 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this truly inline mathematics?  If you're using display math (via `\[` and `\]` (or the non-advised `$$`)), then this would happen automatically.

Comment: I wish to force the document to auto-toggle between the two depending on the expression. Like I said, if i can make a command say ``` \dtfrac{}{} ``` as a general expression for fraction, then say I use it in an integral with limits, then it would use the "\tfrac{}{}" version, else it would just use the "\dfrac{}{}" version.

Comment: why can you not simply use `\frac` ? and use display math environments such as `\[` for the displays then you will not need `$\displaystyle`

Comment: What we're trying to say is that the auto-toggle you're looking for is automatic if you use the display environments `\[`, `equation`, etc.

Comment: But using \[ places the equation right in the middle. It is the same as $$.

Comment: that is why i am avoiding '''\[  \]``` because it places everything in the middle and does not flow on with the sentence structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mathematics environments (e.g. `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` from `amsmath` then most of the maths elements will be in display style but (as you may have noticed) the fractions in your integral limits will still be small (text-style).

The most straightforward approach I can think of is to define a custom command that has the integral `template' how you would like.

To achieve your integral with fractions in both limits, you could use the command (I've named it `\intfrac`) as
`\newcommand{\intfrac}[5]{\displaystyle\int_{\tfrac{#1}{#2}}^{\tfrac{#3}{#4}} #5 }` which you would use (as per your MWE) as
`\intfrac{1}{2}{\pi}{10}{\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}}`
to achieve what you wish. This works both in-line and in a maths environment.

A downside is that this requires you to make a command for every 'instance' of fraction limits - like when only one limit is a fraction. So it's not the best solution, but it may work for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\intfrac}[5]{\displaystyle\int_{\tfrac{#1}{#2}}^{\tfrac{#3}{#4}} #5 }

\begin{document}

% within environment. Notice typical answer has small fractions.
\begin{equation}
\intfrac{1}{2}{\pi}{10}{\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}}\\
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{10}} \frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}
\end{equation}

% in-line environment
$\intfrac{1}{2}{\pi}{10}{\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}}$

% from your MWE
$\displaystyle\int_{\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{10}} \frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}$ \vspace{1cm} %uses \tfrac for limits and \dfrac for fraction

$\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3}{2}}$ \vspace{1cm}  %uses \dfrac because its a fraction 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish to automatically toggle between the two. For example, this approach will still force me to use \intfrac (where ever i have integrals with fractions as limits) and \dfrac where its a normal fraction outside the integral limits. Ideally I would like to use say \dtfrac{}{} and it automatically interprets that hey if its used in an integral, use the \tfrac else use \dfrac.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the switch that you ask for is the standard behaviour of `\frac` using an inline (script) style in the limits and display style in the top level of display math

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{10}} \frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x +3}\]



\[\frac{x^2+x+1}{e^x+\frac{3}{2}}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: But using \[ places the equation right in the middle of the page. It is the same as $$. I want it to go with the flow of the expression.

Comment: @AlanJones `\[` is not the same as `$$` one is a supported latex construct and the other is not. In inline math (`$` or `\(` ) then naturally textstyle fractions are used as inline style aims to preserve the baseline spacing of the surrounding paragraph.

Comment: @AlanJones your examples only had the math expression on the line so display math is more appropriate than inline, Use `[fleqn]` document class option if you want equations flush left not centred.